# SharePoint 2013 copying site with workflows

Tags: sharepoint-2013, sharepoint-workflow

I'm copying a SharePoint subsite of type **"Publishing site with workflow"** to another subsite.

However, SharePoint is not copying the workflow. So the copied subsite becomes a "Publishing site" only.

**Is it possible to copy the site including the publishing workflow?**

Answer (score 0):

if that is not working then another possible way is to backup and restore the subsite using the command.

Take a look at this link and it may help you.

http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/sharepoint/en-US/853d1f95-8ae1-4224-a918-622667f3fa92/backup-and-restore-of-a-particular-subsite-in-sharepoint-2010?forum=sharepointadminprevious

There may any other way to do this but i know this one.

Thanks